# Chrome and Node.js: sometimes the page doesn't load

Tags: javascript, android, node.js, google-chrome

I developed a small web application using Node.js. The core part of the server is:

```
var http = require('http');
var https = require("https");
var privateKey = fs.readFileSync("sslcert/server.key", "utf8");
var certificate = fs.readFileSync("sslcert/server.crt", "utf8");
var credentials = { key: privateKey, cert: certificate};
var httpServer = http.createServer(app);
var httpsServer = https.createServer(credentials, app);

httpServer.listen(80);
httpsServer.listen(443);

...

var app = express();
var routes = require('./routes/index');
app.use(function https(req, res, next){
    if (!req.secure) return res.redirect("https://" + req.headers.host + req.url);
    next();
});

app.use('/', routes);

...

var router = express.Router();
router.get("/", function (req, res, next) {
    res.render("index");
});
```

It works and also redirect the incoming http connections to the https server.

With Chrome for Android, sometimes (I didn't find any criteria) it doesn't load anything (i.e. no activity is shown on the server logs) or it partially loads a page - no errors though. In both case the browser shows a blank page. Refreshing multiple times ofter leads to a normal loading. In few cases I had to exit and run again Chrome.

With Firefox for Android, it always works. 
I'm afraid there are some differences between browsers I'm not aware of.
Where should I look? At the Node.js server code, or in the main "index" view?

Currently I'm testing the server in LAN.

### UPDATE

After debugging a bit I found that there are errors in the console when the page is not loaded (it makes sense, indeed!).

```
Uncaught Error: undefinedModule
    at _f (https://192.168.178.53/javascripts/dojo/dojo.js:8:436)
    at _16 (https://192.168.178.53/javascripts/dojo/dojo.js:8:7573)
    at req (https://192.168.178.53/javascripts/dojo/dojo.js:8:555)
    at _9 (https://192.168.178.53/javascripts/dojox/mobile/parser.js:11:42)
    at _7.parse (https://192.168.178.53/javascripts/dojox/mobile/parser.js:102:4)
    at https://192.168.178.53/:66:12
    at _ce (https://192.168.178.53/javascripts/dojo/dojo.js:8:11949)
    at _37 (https://192.168.178.53/javascripts/dojo/dojo.js:8:13569)
    at https://192.168.178.53/javascripts/dojo/dojo.js:8:13833
    at _38 (https://192.168.178.53/javascripts/dojo/dojo.js:8:13659)
```

and

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'set' of undefined
    at https://192.168.178.53/:315:33
    at _ce (https://192.168.178.53/javascripts/dojo/dojo.js:8:11949)
    at _37 (https://192.168.178.53/javascripts/dojo/dojo.js:8:13569)
    at https://192.168.178.53/javascripts/dojo/dojo.js:8:13833
    at _38 (https://192.168.178.53/javascripts/dojo/dojo.js:8:13659)
    at _81 (https://192.168.178.53/javascripts/dojo/dojo.js:8:13758)
    at _f6 (https://192.168.178.53/javascripts/dojo/dojo.js:8:15537)
    at HTMLScriptElement._10b (https://192.168.178.53/javascripts/dojo/dojo.js:8:18464)
```

The only references to my code are at line 66 and line 315.
Line 66 is just the parser invocation in the head section:

```
 require([
    "dojox/mobile/parser",
    "dojox/mobile/View",
    "dojox/mobile/Button",
    "dojox/mobile/TextBox",
    "dojox/mobile/RoundRect",
    "dojox/mobile/FilteredListMixin",
    "dojox/mobile/TextArea",
    "dojox/mobile/Switch",
    "dojox/mobile/FormLayout",
    "dojox/mobile/SimpleDialog",
    "dojo/domReady!"
], function (parser) {
    parser.parse();
});
```

while line 315 is included in this short snippet, executed on startup:

```
var userName = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("userName"));
if (userName != undefined && userName.length) {
    registry.byId("txtName").set("value", userName); // line 315
}
```

As far I as understand the console error is saying it "cannot read property (?!) set of undefined". Set is a method anyway. 
I guess it doesn't find the `txtName` widget. It is defined as:

```
input#txtName.login(type="text" data-dojo-type="dojox/mobile/TextBox" data-dojo-props="selectOnClick:true, placeHolder:'Username'" name="name" required)
```

and the snippet above as `dojo/domReady!` as last item of the require array.
It appears weird to me because FireFox doesn't throw such errors. 
Do you see any evidence of wrong code here?

Comment: Seems to be an issue with the view. Server code shouldn't affect the browser. You may want to post the client side code.

Comment: I can't really post all the code here: it'is over 2500 lines, without the third party js. But after your comment I'm going to narrow the focus, commenting out most of code, unless I find a very short snippet that still has the described behavior.